# Python Lazy Loading Property not working for Class method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class `Foo` that uses lazy loading for `Foo.bar`.

```
class Foo(object):

    @property
    def bar(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_bar'):
            self._initBar()
        return self._bar

    def _initBar(self):
        self._bar = 'bar'

foo = Foo()
print(foo.bar)    # prints "bar"
```

However when i try to convert `Foo` to use class methods only, `Foo.bar` is not giving me `bar`, but instead giving:

```
<property object at 0x000001CA1C344728>
```

Why is it not giving me `bar`?

```
class Foo(object):

    @property
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_bar'):
            cls._initBar()
        return cls._bar

    @classmethod
    def _initBar(cls):
        cls._bar = 'bar'

print(Foo.bar)    # prints "<property object at 0x000001CA1C344728>"
```

Comment: "However when i try to convert Foo to use class methods only" - why would you do that? What is the point of having this class at all?

Comment: Descriptors (e.g. properties) only work when accessed through instances. To make a property work on the class, you'd have to define it on that class's metaclass.

Comment: @user2357112 `bar` is actually for lazy loading a MySQL connection.

Comment: @Nyxynyx that isn't the question. The question is why create a class with only classmethods? That doesn't make much sense. Why not just a module? Why not normal methods?

Comment: @kindall: Descriptor `__get__` methods are invoked when the descriptor is accessed through the class, but `property.__get__` doesn't invoke the getter in that case.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The class also contains instance methods. I am thinking of creating a class method which accepts a list of the class instances. Should I be creating a new class like `FooProcessor`  and instantiate it to process several `Foo` objects?

Comment: @Nyxynyx sounds like a more sane approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Are you recommending the creation of a new class `FooProcessor` instead?

Comment: @Nyxynyx it would be my first instinct, but it's more of a matter of opinion/stylistic taste as well. I tend to *almost never* use `classmethod` (and I **never** use staticmethod).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `property` built-in is a handy tool in Python that presents an easy use case of a more powerful mechanism, which is the "descriptor protocol".

Basically, any object when retrieved from an instance or from a class is first checked if it has one of `__get__`, `__set__` or `__del__` methods.  `property` wraps getter functions to be called by `__get__` when the attribute is retrieved from an instance, but returns the property object itself when it is retrieved from the class instead. (That is even a common use case for other descriptors)

Thus, if you want a `property` like behavior for class attributes, you have to create your own descriptor class, sporting the `__get__` method - or, simply create your class with a metaclass, and use `property` as is, on the metaclass.  The drawbacks of the later are many: you willneed one custom metaclass for each class where you want the managed class attributes being just the first of them. On the other hand, creating your own descriptor is quite easy:

```
class MyProperty:
    def __init__(self, initializer):
        self.initializer = initializer

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not hasattr(owner, "_" + self.name):
            initializer = getattr(owner, self.initializer)
            initializer()      

        return getattr(owner, "_" + self.name)


class Foo:   

    bar = MyProperty("_initBar")

    @classmethod
    def _initBar(cls):
        cls._bar = 'bar'
```

Please note that `__set_name__` is only implemented from Python 3.6 on. On older Python's, including Python 2.x, you should use:

```
class MyProperty(object):
   def __init__(self, initializer, name):
       self.initializer = initializer
      self.name = name

   def __get__(self, instance, owner):
       if not hasattr(owner, "_" + self.name):
           initializer = getattr(owner, self.initializer)
           initializer(owner)      

       return getattr(owner, "_" + self.name)


class Foo(object):

    bar = MyProperty("_initBar", name='bar')

    @classmethod
    def _initBar(cls):
        cls._bar = 'bar'
```

Comment: ahhhh the neglected `owner` parameter!

Comment: Update: on testng I changed the intial code to take the initializer as a string with its name instead, as during class construction,  "classmethod" is quite a different beast than what you retrieve after the class is created, as it is itself a descriptor with a behavior set when retrieved from its class.

Answer (score 2):

You **could** use a metaclass, because `property` objects are meant to be accessed through the *instance* and if your intended instance is the *class itself*, then you need to put the property on the class of the class, i.e. the metaclass:

```
In [37]: class MetaFoo(type):
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def bar(cls):
    ...:         if not hasattr(cls, '_bar'):
    ...:             print("hard at work!")
    ...:             cls._init_bar()
    ...:         return cls._bar
    ...:

In [38]: class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def _init_bar(cls):
    ...:         cls._bar = 'bar'
    ...:

In [39]: Foo.bar
hard at work!
Out[39]: 'bar'

In [40]: Foo.bar
Out[40]: 'bar'
```

Of course, while this may be possible, <strike>I'm agnostic about whether or not</strike> it is **not** *advisable*.

### Edit

As @jsbueno demonstrates, it is much more sane to simply define your own descriptor, which can give you a much more flexible behavior.

Comment: it is not advisable. Even as you wrote this, I was writting my own answer and put there one of many motives why not to do it.  :-)